# How to append from the asset browser instead of linking?

Tags: asset-browser

I'm trying to append assets from the asset browser but all the objects are linked, I need them to be editable, so it's better to append them instead of linking. I tried making it local, making it single user, but nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

At the center of the top bar of the *Asset Browser*, in the dropdown menu choose *Append* instead of *Link* (but a linked object can still be unlinked if needed):

[image]